# Where is the default Windows 8 MIDI soundfont located?

Tags: midi, windows, soundfont

I am trying to find the default soundfont that Windows 8 uses to play MIDI files so that I can have another program play them back and sound the same as Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gm.dls` file is typically located in `C:\windows\system32\drivers`.

However, the file `gmreadme.txt` right near it says:

```
The GM.DLS file contains the Roland SoundCanvas Sound Set which is
protected under the following copyright:
Roland GS Sound Set/Microsoft (P) 1996 Roland Corporation U.S.
The Roland SoundCanvas Sound Set is licensed under Microsoft's
End User License Agreement for use with Microsoft operating
system products only.  All other uses require a separate written
license from Roland.
```